# How to customize the Paragraph tag in CSS?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I use the SharePoint Online Wikilibrary, which is a library with html-pages.
When I type text on these pages. The text will be formatted with the Paragraph tag automatically.
So instead of:

**Example1**
One
Two
Three

I get:

**Example2**

One

Two

Three

How to customize the tag Paragraph in CSS so i get the text like the example 1 ?
Thank you in advanced,

Greetings, P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I type the text on the page directly.
[image]
It does not reproduce your issue.
You can use edit source to check the structure of the code that has been converted into html.
[image]

```
<div>One Two Three<br/><br/></div>
```